# I restored my windows 10 machine, but windows.old will not deleted, have tried unlocker, diskcleanup etc

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have 2 folders, both are windows.old, one is in c:/ and the other is in c:/xampp3/ (kek) I have tried deleting them with every artcle I can find and none seem to be working (because these are being used in another process, or sometimes being used in windows defender (wtf) lol)

When I try to delete I get the following

[image]

Inside the windows.old the 2 folder that refuse to delete are program files, with windows defender in

[image]

and the other folder

[image]

and the c:/windows.old

[image]

[image]

Windows seems to being usin the proccesses from windows.old, but I have a new windows folder, and I even added the windows.old folder and xamppp (with the other windows.old) folder over to my documents, so it actually moves, just won't delete

[image]

Comment: If you follow the directions within the accepted answer that I referenced in that duplicate question, you should be able to delete the `windows.old` folder without any problem.  I would move the folders back to their original locations and proceed with caution while you follow through on each step.

Comment: is windows.old in xammp a junction or link? What happens if you shut down xampp services? Check the xampp folder using Junction? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Comment: I don't have xampp (I did, but windows old somehow ended up in there)

Comment: Just use the Cleanup Tool.

Comment: @Ramhound, a very good suggestion and the OP didn't specifically mention it within the main body of his text, but the question's title implies that he already tried that.